# Unity add a sdk got the `no resources found` error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, helpshift

I use a Unity to create my game. And I integrate a SDK. When I build to the APK, I got a error.

> Error:(238) Error retrieving parent for item:
>    No resource found that matches the given name'Animation.AppCompat.Dialog'.
>   Error:(256) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1'.
>   Error:(259) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption'.
>   Error:(260) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption'.
>   Error:(263) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption'.
>   Error:(266) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption'.
>   Error:(273) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button'.
>   Error:(276, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textAllCaps'.
>   Error:(278) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat'.
>   Error:(281) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Dialog'.
>   Error:(286) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
>   Error:(289) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog'.
>   Error:(295, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.
>   Error:(296, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.
>   Error:(299, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.
>   Error:(300, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.
>   Error:(306, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
>   Error:(324, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'backgroundTint'.
>   Error:(326, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
>   Error:(332, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
>   Error:(346, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
>   Error:(238) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Animation.AppCompat.Dialog'.
>   Error:(256) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1'.
>   Error:(259) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption'.
>   Error:(260) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption'.
>   Error:(263) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption'.
>   Error:(266) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption'.
>   Error:(273) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button'.
>   Error:(276, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textAllCaps'.
>   Error:(278) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat'.
>   Error:(281) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Dialog'.
>   Error:(286) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
>   Error:(289) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog'.
>   Error:(295, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.
>   Error:(296, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.
>   Error:(299, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.
>   Error:(300, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.
>   Error:(306, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
>   Error:(324, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'backgroundTint'.
>   Error:(326, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
>   Error:(332, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
>   Error:(346, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':design-26.0.2:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Here is my gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
      flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
      }
   }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name: 'GoogleAIDL', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'GooglePlay', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'UnityAds', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'common', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'installreferrer-1.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'simple-android-notifications', ext:'aar')
    compile project(':SuperAwesome_lib')
    compile project(':answers')
    compile project(':appcompat-v7-26.0.2')
    compile project(':beta')
    compile project(':cardview-v7-26.0.2')
    compile project(':crashlytics')
    compile project(':crashlytics-wrapper')
    compile project(':design-26.0.2')
    compile project(':fabric')
    compile project(':fabric-init')
    compile project(':helpshift')
    compile project(':recyclerview-v7-26.0.2')
    compile project(':support-annotations-26.0.2')
    compile project(':support-compat-26.0.2')
    compile project(':support-core-ui-26.0.2')
    compile project(':support-core-utils-26.0.2')
    compile project(':support-fragment-26.0.2')
    compile project(':support-transition-26.0.2')
    compile project(':support-v4-26.0.2')
    compile project(':support-vector-drawable-26.0.2')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion   16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        applicationId 'xxxx'
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
        }
        versionCode 25
        versionName '1.0.15'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress '.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb','crashlytics-build.properties'
    }

    signingConfigs { release {
        storeFile file('keystore')
        storePassword 'x'
        keyAlias 'x'
        keyPassword 'x'
    } }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip "*/armeabi-v7a/*.so"
        doNotStrip "*/x86/*.so"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your SDK depends an Android Framework: appcompat-v7-2x.x.x.aar, so just put a v7 library into your project directory like "Assets/Plugins/Android". See this:
[AppCompatDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDialog).

Comment: Hello, where can I find the *.aar?

Comment: @manlokmanlok Just search in your Android SDK: AndroidSDK\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7\